# Resizing image-pixel arrays with Pillow

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I'm working through one of the O'Reilly media books titled, "Programming Computer Vision with Python", in which one of the exercises is to use pca on a set of images, with the aim of displaying the 'mean' image and the first seven modes; the directions with the most variation. Running the code should give eight images in one figure window. I've copied their code directly, and am using my own set of 55 images (handwritten letter 'a') each 900 x 1200 in dimension. The issue is that the dimensions of the image matrix resulting from flattening the images is (1 x 3240000).

```
#create a matrix to store all flattened images

immatrix = array([array(Image.open(im)).flatten() for im in imlist], 'f')
```

I scratched my head for a bit, until I realized that this is simply 900 x 1200 x 3 for the three color channels. That said, the code example in the book says nothing about this, and simply tries to resize the (1 x 3240000) array into a 900 x 1200 image, which numpy is of course complaining about.

```
# show some images (mean and 7 first modes)

figure()
gray()
subplot(2,4,1)
imshow(immean.reshape(m,n))  # Issue, array is 3240000, because of the 
                             # 3 color channels. m = 900 and n = 1200
for i in range(7):
    subplot(2, 4, i+2)
    imshow(V[i].reshape(m,n))

show()
```

If anyone has experience with this or can help, that would be wonderful. As a note, I started working with Pillow roughly 2 hours ago, so *specific* examples for the fix would be more helpful than a general conceptual answer. Thank you very much! I've included the full code below.

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
import pca
import os


imlist = [os.path.join("imlist", f) for f in os.listdir("imlist") if 
f.endswith('.png')]



im = array(Image.open(imlist[0])) #open one image to get size
m,n = im.shape[0:2] #get the size of the images, which is 900 x 1200


imnbr = len(imlist) #get the number of images
print (imnbr)


#create a matrix to store all flattened images

immatrix = array([array(Image.open(im)).flatten() for im in imlist], 'f')
V,S,immean = pca.pca(immatrix)
(V, S,immean)

# show some images (mean and 7 first modes)

figure()
gray()
subplot(2,4,1)
imshow(immean.reshape(m,n))  # Issue, array is 3240000, because of the 3 color channels. m = 900 and n = 1200
for i in range(7):
    subplot(2, 4, i+2)
    imshow(V[i].reshape(m,n))

show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the code you are using assumes the images are grey-scale images.
So an easy way to fix the code would be to change `Image.open(im)` to

```
Image.open(im).convert('L')
```

to [convert](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) your RGB images (three 8-bit channels) to grey-scale images (having one 8-bit channel).

---

Another option would be to change the [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) calls to

```
plt.imshow(immean.reshape(m,n,3))
```

and (inside the for-loop)

```
plt.imshow(V[i].reshape(m,n,3))
```